# How to open a latex file in read mode in python

Tags: python, scripting, latex

**PHP**, actually I am creating a python script to analysis and count the number of acronyms in latex(.tex) file.

```
from sympy.interactive import printing
printing.init_printing(use_latex = True)


import sympy
import pandas
import os

#file = open("AS_in_CR_OC_JOUR_v1.tex","r")
import re
cnt = 0
with open('AS_in_CR_OC_JOUR_v1.tex') as myfile:
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    length = len(lines)
    for line in lines:
        if re.search(r'\b[A-Z]{2}\b', line) is not None:
            cnt += 1

print("{:.1f}%".format(cnt/length*100))
file.close() 
print("Number of acronyms in a tex file:", cnt)
```

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: I have upload the code that I am trying, but I am not sure about it.

Comment: can you help me with a python code to count the no. of acronyms in txt and shortlisting them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like [Pylatex](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/) which offers as much flexibility as you need.

In your case, I would suggest finding the documentation on how to `read` latex files which should be on that website.